# Как подключить русский язык в шаблоне overleaf?

Tags: latex

На сайте overleaf очень много классных шаблонов для статей, конкретно меня интересует вот этот: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-blackwell-science-tellus-b-journal/tjtqqxsnhjwj

но он ломается (шрифт перестает выделяется жирным/курсивом и т.д.), когда я добавляю команду \usepackage[russian]{babel}

может быть, кто-то знает, что можно еще добавить, чтобы все заработало? или у кого-то есть классный похожий русский шаблон?

Answer (score 2):

В данном шаблоне (как и во многих других от зарубежных авторов/издателей) используется шрифт times (Adobe Times), и этот шаблон не был рассчитан для использования с языками, у которых алфавит отличается от латинского. То есть в этих шрифтах times просто нет кириллицы. И при компиляции latex использует для  русских символов стандартный шрифт cmr (Computer Modern), при этом, убирая все модификации (курсив, жирность и т.п.). Поэтому "что-то добавить, чтобы все заработало" без изменения внешнего вида будет сложно. Но есть варианты.

Естественно, для всех дальнейших модификаций нужно добавить в преамбулу:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % зависит от кодировки Вашего документа
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}  % если использовать вставки на английском не нужно, то можно в параметрах оставить только 'russian'
```

1. Самый простой способ - если Вам не важно сохранить текущий шрифт, то можно просто вернуть все настройки шрифтов к стандартному в latex Computer Modern:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
   \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmt}
   ```
2. Если очень хочется добиться полного совпадения по шрифту, то... Можно попробовать включить шрифты от Paratype `\usepackage{paratype}`. В нем шрифт с засечками напоминает times. Но, если я верно понял, у этого набора шрифтов для кириллицы нет капители (small caps).

   Еще можно отдельно установить пакет pscyr и использовать шрифты из его набора (буквы из рубленых и моноширинных шрифтов в этом пакете выглядят слишком широкими, поэтому лучше оставить эти шрифты стандартными, из набора CM-Super):

   ```
   \usepackage{pscyr}
   \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}
   \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmt}
   ```

   В принципе, вместо шрифта TimesNewRomanPSMT (ftm) можно использовать гарнитуру AntiquaPSCyr (faq) - это аналог гарнитуры Литературная, и она может смотреться лучше, чем Times New Roman. Для использования Antiqua, можно не переопределять явно команду `\rmdefault`, так как эта гарнитура включается в пакете pscyr по умолчанию:

   ```
   \usepackage{pscyr}
   \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
   \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmt}
   ```

   Остальные две команды нужно переопределять, т.к. они задаются пакетом times (который подгружает класс документа).

   Со шрифтами PSCyr есть только одна проблема: их не включают в дистрибутивы из-за каких-то лицензионных конфликтов с отдельными гарнитурами (при том, что автор пакета все буквы рисовал сам и ничего не заимствовал), поэтому, этот пакет нужно устанавливать руками. И да, если далее у документа будет какое-то коммерческое использование, то эти лицензионные проблемы могут дотянуться и до автора документа. Я предупредил :-).

   Еще можно использовать вместо times пакет literat: пакет есть на CTAN, но не включается в дистрибутивы tex-а из-за несоответствия лицензий, кажется. В общем, его тоже нужно устанавливать вручную (в TeXLive он устанавливается с другими "несвободными шрифтами" с помощью скрипта `install-getnonfreefonts` (искать на сайте [texlive](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/))).

   Также как и с пакетом pscyr, нужно будет переопределеить пару команд:

   ```
   \usepackage{literat}
   \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
   \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmt}
   ```
3. Этот вариант был подсмотрен на английском [SE по TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331324/156180) (и его можно использовать в сочетании со шрифтами, например, от Paratype).
   Если можно в изображении кириллицы немного отойти от стиля Times до "что-то похожее на Times", то можно использовать еще и такой вариант: есть пакет, который делает подстановку шрифтов для отсутствующих символов, и тогда для латинских букв можно использовать times, а для кириллицы можно взять шрифт Tempora-TLF (похожий на times). У него нет капители для кириллицы, но это можно обойти.

   ```
    \usepackage{substitutefont}
    \substitutefont{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}
    \makeatletter
    \input{t2atempora-tlf.fd}
    \DeclareFontShape{T2A}{Tempora-TLF}{m}{sc}{
        <-> ssub * Tempora-TLF/m/n
    }{}
    \makeatother
   ```

   Этот шрифт включен в оба дистрибутива latex (MikTeX и TeXLive).